# htaccess 301 redirect rules issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a simple redirection, but I encounter this error, when I do the 301 redirect using the htaccess, it returns the redirect but with the value

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^clientes/(\w+)/?$ clientes.php?id=$1 [L]

Redirect 301 /clientes/juan http://google.es
```

**result:**

```
https://www.google.es/?id=juan&gws_rd=ssl
```

Comment: Can you please update the post with the input URL and what you're expecting as output?

Comment: url without "id=juan" for exemple http://www.google.es

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are mixing mod-alias (Redirect) with mod-rewrite (RewriteRule) . These are two diffrent modules with diffrent runtime behaviour .

Try using this :

```
RewriteRule ^clientes/juan http://google.com [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^clientes/(\w+)/?$ clientes.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing these rules.

Comment: In the example it works, thanks @starteen

But on the site I'm dealing with this issue, I do not: 

`code`
Rewriterule ^videos/(.*)_(.*).html$ index.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
Rewriterule ^videos/(.*).html$ index.php?tag=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/videos/juan.html https://www.dominio .com/categoria/juanes [R=301,L]
`code`

Answer (score 0):

this working, but my problem is with this line.

```
Rewriterule ^videos/(.*)_(.*).html$ index.php?tag=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
Rewriterule ^videos/(.*).html$ index.php?tag=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/videos/juan.html https://www.dominio .com/cat/conduccion-juan/ [R=301,L]
```

and this not working

```
redirect 301 /videos/juan.html https://www.dominio.com/videos/conduccion-juan.html
```

thank you!